# Annoying spacing in gnuplot pm3d color maps

Tags: dictionary, colors, gnuplot, space

I've produced the following image:

[image]

where there is this little blank space between the pm3d map and the two side profiles and it's kinda annoying. I suspect it may be due to the profiles (the gaussians) being slighly large, but, isn't that controlled by the margins definements?

The gnuplot code is:

```
set encoding utf8
set term x11
set terminal pngcairo dashed nocrop size 640,560 enhanced solid color font 'Helvetica,12' butt dashed
set output "E_vs_eta_big_N4.png"
set multiplot
set lmargin screen 0.20
set rmargin screen 0.85
set bmargin screen 0.25
set tmargin screen 0.90

set hidden3d
set pm3d map
#set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
#set samples 50, 50
#set isosamples 50, 50
set xrange [ -3 : 3 ]
set yrange [ -3 : 3 ]
#set cbrange [ 0 : 1.000 ]
#set cbtics -0.25,0.25,1
set cblabel "{/Symbol h}"
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset key

splot "gfock_pair_correlation_N4_L0.txt" u 1:2:6
unset pm3d

set lmargin screen 0.10
set rmargin screen 0.20
set ytics
set yrange [ -3.00 : 3.00 ]
set ylabel "y"
unset xlabel
set xrange [*:*]
set surface

plot "gfock_pair_correlation_N4_L0.txt" u 6:2 w lines lc rgb "green"

set lmargin screen 0.20
set rmargin screen 0.85
set bmargin screen 0.15
set tmargin screen 0.25
set xrange [ -3.00 : 3.00 ]
set yrange [ * : * ]
unset ylabel
set xlabel "x"
set xtics
unset ytics

plot "gfock_pair_correlation_N4_L0.txt" u 1:6
unset multiplot
set term x11
```

Comment: I don't have these with gnuplot 5.0.3 (but I replaced your datafiles with function exp(-x²y²), maybe the issue is with your data or datafile related, please post them if the gap disappears in your config when using a function instead of file)

Comment: @Joce I just tried plotting a simple exp(-x²) but the gap is still there. :/

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, tried gnuplot 4.6 and 5.0

Comment: What version of gnuplot do you have? Then, if you think it's an issue with the side plots having a white background overlapping with nearby plot in the version of `term png` that you have, why don't you plot the side plots first and then the colour map?

Comment: My gnuplot is 4.6. @Joce Plotting the side profiles first doesn't help. What I could do was to plot the colormaps within the range [-2.85:2.85] with which the blank space vanished. That's really odd, since `png` usually don't give this kind of problems.